# (DOORS DXL) Creating title page in Word with different size/color text

Tags: ibm-doors

I currently have a script that creates an HTML page that shows the differences in scripts that were made since the previous baseline and then saves it as a Word document.  Now, what I'd like to do is add a title page with text that is of a different color and size than the main document.  This text will also need to be centered to make it look more like the other documents our company makes.  Luckily, the title of the document will be the same for all versions, so I'm adding this part of the script to before it adds the differences.  However, I'm not sure how to make the text display as a different color and size before adding a "new page" break for the rest of the document.  Can somebody help me out with how to add the text and new page to the front of the current document?

Chris

Comment: You want to know how to style HTML to a different colour? Suggest you search for html or css tutorials, there are plenty out there.

Comment: What I want to do is add a title page to the front of the document file, not the HTML.

Comment: not sure how your script works, but it sounds like you can use OLE Automation to communicate wits MS Word. Basically, you have to create a VBA script and transfer every call to Word to OLE Automation calls.

Comment: Unfortunately, the another problem is that I can't include a Word template with the script.  I need to do it from within my DXL script so I can't use Word VBA to create the title page.  As I said, the script is creating the Word document, it just needs to add a title page to the front of the document.  I _italic_could create the title page first, but if I do that, how would I add a new page after it to place the contents of the HTML file?